# "Subscript out of Range" error appears on second run of VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

So I know this question gets asked a lot, and I know the answer 99 times out of a hundred is that the worksheet name isn't valid or is incorrect in the code. But I'm certain that this isn't the case

However, if I'm making a very silly error, I apologize. I'm very new to VBA, and have just been given this task.

So the code below is just to go through two columns in different spreadsheets and search for  similarities. It's very simple at the moment as I'm really only at the start so consistently getting this error is slowing down progress.

When I run the code once, it completes, does what I expect it to do and gives no errors. But when I run it a second time with no changes the Run-time error 9 window appears. However if I close all spreadsheets involved in the code and reopen them, the code runs successfully again.

I've looked into the error quite a bit, but couldn't find anything relevant. I think that it's something really simple I'm missing, and I just don't have the experience to see it. Which is why I'm here

So I've changed the name of the sheets, the location, and I've run similar code in different spreadsheets, without coming into the same error. So it does seem like the name of the sheets would be wrong. But if that's the case it shouldn't run the first time. Or when I close and reopen them.

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\CMM Update\CMM.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("CMM")

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\CMM Update\04-Jul.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Data")

For Each cell In ws1.Range("B1:B25")
    If cell.Value = ws2.Range("A1").Value Then
        MsgBox "Active Cell"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Active Cell"

   End If
Next cell     

End Sub
```

Comment: could you change that line to `Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)` and see whether the error appears?

Comment: If you want to run multiple times, then you need to keep a reference to the open workbooks and reuse that, instead of calling `Workbooks.Open()` every time. Also try with a `For` loop and use `ws2.Range("B1").Cells(i,1)` to read each value.

Answer (score 0):

If my suspicion is correct and the macro fails because the workbooks are already opened, try the following. It checks if the workbooks are already open:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

'Test if wb1 is open
On Error Resume Next
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\CMM Update\CMM.xlsm")
On Error GoTo 0
If err.Number <> 0 Then Set wb1 = Workbooks("CMM")
err.Clear

'Test if wb2 is open
On Error Resume Next
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\CMM Update\04-Jul.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If err.Number <> 0 Then Set wb2 = Workbooks("04-Jul")
err.Clear

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("CMM")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Data")

For Each cell In ws1.Range("B1:B25")
    If cell.Value = ws2.Range("A1").Value Then
        MsgBox "Active Cell"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Active Cell"
   End If
Next cell     

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Tim, but no change. As an aside, after "On Error GoTo 0", should wb1 be set as "Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\CMM Update\CMM.xlsm")" rather than  workbooks("CMM"). I'm just wondering if vba would be able to find the workbook if it's not directed to the location. I could be totally off, I'm just curious.

Comment: It appears on  "Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("CMM")"

Comment: Can you confirm that `wb1` actually holds a workbook object? If it does, then it can't find the sheet named "CMM". Try returning the sheet's correct name with `Debug.Print wb1.Sheets(1)` (or whatever the right index is)

Comment: About your question, if there is an error opening the wb it might already be open, that's why I set the wb reference to the open workbook with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it was something very simple. i just needed to add ActiveWorkbook.close to the end of the loop.

Thanks for the help Mike. It was your last comment that made me realize that the error was coming about because the workbook was still open. That's how much of newb I am to VBA.